# How do I check if there is a variable inside a 2d list?

Tags: python, arrays, list

I am trying to make code that asks what movie you would like to know about and gives you the movie + the director + a rating.

```
movieDirectorRatingList = [
    ["Munich: The Edge of War", "Christian Schwochow", "4.1"],
    ["Avengers:Endgame", "Anthony Russo, Joe Russo and Joss Whedon", "4.8"],
    ["Tombstone", "Cosmatos and Kevin Jarre", "4.1"],
    ["Waterloo", "George P.","Sergei Bondarchuk", "4.0"],
    ["Iron Man", "Jon Favreau", "4.9"]
]

movieSelection = input("What movie would you like to know about?")

if movieSelection in movieDirectorRatingList:
    movieLocation = movieDirectorRatingList.count(movieSelection) - 1 
    print(f"{movieSelection} directed by {movieDirectorRatingList[movieLocation][2]}{movieDirectorRatingList[movieLocation][3]}" )

elif movieSelection not in movieDirectorRatingList:
    print("Movie not in list")

else:
    print("An unexpected error has occured")
```

I managed to have it working when I used 1-dimensional lists, but when I use 2 dimensional ones it says the Movie isn't in the list. Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: You need a dictionary (dict), not a list of lists. Check on the docs you are using to learn Python about dicts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate through each list:

```py
for movie in movieDirectorRatingList:
    title, director, rating = movie # let's unpack these here
    if movieSelection in movie:
        print(f"{movieSelection} directed by {director} {rating}" )
        break # found the movie
else:
    print("Movie selection not found")
```

Comment: this, while solves the specific problem in the question, does not help their learning of the language and proper use of data structures - this is case where a dictionary would be better.

Comment: @jsbueno I can appreciate that, but they are still lacking in understanding this particular data structure. Would a dictionary be better here to solve the problem? Yes. But it doesn't explain why they are having trouble in this case

Answer (score 1):

I used your code and reformatted it and made this. It does what I believe you want, but slightly simpler.

```
mdrl = [
    ["Munich: The Edge of War", "Christian Schwochow", "4.1"],
    ["Avengers:Endgame", "Anthony Russo, Joe Russo and Joss Whedon", "4.8"],
    ["Tombstone", "Cosmatos and Kevin Jarre", "4.1"],
    ["Waterloo", "George P. and Sergei Bondarchuk", "4.0"],
    ["Iron Man", "Jon Favreau", "4.9"]
]

movieChoice = input("Which movie would you like to get data from?: ")

for i in range(len(mdrl)):
    if mdrl[i][0] == movieChoice:
        print(mdrl[i][0], "Was directed by", mdrl[i][1], "and had a rating of ", mdrl[i][2])
```

P.S. I changed a piece of data from your "waterloo" data due to their being two directors being in two different sections in the array.